# Are pre-existing files in a mountpoint directory safe and uneffected?

Tags: filesystem, mount, umount

I've noticed that pre-existing files in a "mountpoint" directory *disappear* when the **mount** command is applied... and then they re-appear when the directory is **unmounted**.

Are these files just on "holiday" for the duration of the mount period? ... are they safe? ... and is there some way to still access them while the mount is active?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't worry about your files, they won't be overwritten while the directory they're in is used as a mount point. Unfortunately, when you mount over that directory they are completely invisible to the system. There's no trivial way you can access them while the directory is being used as a mount point. If you need to use them, you'll have to unmount the filesystem there first.

Comment: Thanks... Here's a litlle experiment I just tried, which *pre-emptively* gives me access to the hidden files (I can't see why it would be of any use, but it does work):-- **mntDir1** has **file1** and  **mntDir2** is empty -- `mount mntDir1 mntDir2` (mntDir2 now shows file1) -- `mount /dev/sdc1 mntDir1` (mntDir1 show *only* sdc1 files.. and mntDir2 *still* shows file1 which is "normally" accessible) -- Just a point of interest :)

Comment: Interesting workaround =) but why wouldn't you just mount /dev/sdc1 to mntDir2?

Comment: I guess it might be useful if the files on /dev/sdc1 need to be available at the mntDir1 path for some reason, but you still want access to the original files that were there...  (of course, it still sounds more like a temporary workaround than something you want to use long-term).

Comment: Another workaround: use hard links on the files inside the directory of the mount point

Comment: Thanks for clarity. This is indeed funny and unbelievable that such a bizarre way of making set of file invisible without letting user know, is allowed by such a proven system

Answer (score 2):

Files are safe as mentioned in @codeMonks answer.

But there's a safer workaround to access the files. Let's say that you have existing directory `/data/media/` with assorted media files (`/data` and `/data/media` are on the same filesystem)

Now mounting something like over `/data/media`  will hide files that it contained. (lets assume that you've added usbdrive `/dev/sdb1` and mounted it over  `/data/media`)

To access files in `/data/media`:
To be on the safe side, first create empty directory `/mnt/mymedia`
and then use `mount --bind` (works on directory level)

```
sudo mount --bind  /data /mnt/mymedia/
```

Please note that you have to use the upperdir `/data` if you're mounting after usb drive! But if you used

```
sudo mount --bind  /data/media /mnt/mymedia/
```

**before** mounting said usbdrive you can still access you original files from `/mnt/mymedia`